# Feign logging for HTTP POST with multipart/form-data content type

Tags: spring, cloud, multipart, form-data, feign

I am doing some tests with Feign logger and have observed that with Feign logging level set to FULL and package logging level set to DEBUG, this Feign API logs the body;

```
@Headers(value={"Content-Type: application/json", "X-Auth-Username: {authUsername}"})
```

but this API does not log the body;

```
@Headers(value={"Content-Type: multipart/form-data", "X-Auth-Username: {authUsername}"})
```

The reason is that code in feign.Logger class requires a charset to be associated with the content type before it will print it;

```
        if (logLevel.ordinal() >= Level.FULL.ordinal()) {
      String bodyText =
          request.charset() != null ? new String(request.body(), request.charset()) : null;
```

[RFC 7578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578#section-8) does not allow a charset parameter for the multipart/form-data content type.

I can write a custom logger to work around this but is this an omission in Feign logging ? or is there a deliberate strategy behind it.